# SSH linux root user has clipboard access but I cannot access clipboard with user I created

Tags: ssh, remote, clipboard, rdp, copy-and-paste

I am using linux for the first time in my life. I bought a dedicated server and installed the Ubuntu 20.04 desktop LTS distribution in it. local system is windows. I created a user in linux and I added it to the sudo group. While I can paste something I copied from windows to the terminal or mousepad in the root user, I cannot do this in the other user I created.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop